# android app design looks different on lollipop than marshmallow

Tags: android-layout, android-6.0-marshmallow, android-5.1.1-lollipop

My application uses tabs with icon and text.

On Marshmallow the icons look fine but not in Lollipop.

Can you please help?

Here is how it looks on Marshmallow (and Nougat):

[image: Here is how it looks on Marshmallow (and Nougat):]

And here is how it looks on Lollipop:

[image: And here is how it looks on Lollipop:]

I should mention that the icons are added as drawables.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list
      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
      <item android:drawable="@drawable/myicon75x75"
            android:gravity="top"
            android:height="30dp"
            android:width="30dp" >
      </item>
</layer-list>
```

Comment: this is the issue of your device resolution. Add multiple size of images in hdpi,mdpi,xhdpi and xxhdpi and the problem will be resolved.   On resolution change, devices tries to adjust images automatically and here we need multiple size images for saving our application to look ugly in different devices

Comment: Use your comment as an answer and I will accept it as selected answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For images in your application to support multiple screen size, you need to put multiple size of images in your drawable folder.
e.g., drawable-hdpi, drawable-mdpi, drawable-xhdpi, drawable-xxhdpi and put correct images in the respective folders. 

 Now even if your device's screen resolution changes, your application images will not get affected by it. 

Also, you can easily get multiple size of icons from [this link](http://www.flaticon.com/).